# Continuous repaint events in Windows-7, wxWidgets

Tags: windows-7, wxwidgets, repaint

On Windows-7 my application receives continuous repaint events from windows.  I am using wxWidgets.

The problem does not occur:

- On winXP,
- On Linux,

in debug mode of Visual Studio (2010)

The problem only occurs in Widows-7 when the app is redrawing a lot and it takes more than 5 seconds to draw.  If I turn off some of what needs to be redrawn, and it doesn't take as long, it is fine.

I am calling `wxPaintDC dc(this);` in the paint event handler so this is not the problem.

I tried `DwmFlush` as well.  I put it in the repaint event handler and also in the drawing code.

Comment: IIRC Windows 7 has something built into it that if an application does not process window messages for 5 seconds then it considers the application to have hung and puts a ghost window on top of the hung application. That's probably what causes it, you can verify by disabling the service responsible (I think it's the DWM Session Manager), but to fix it you'd need to either process window messages while you are drawing (which sounds pretty ropey), or only do small parts of drawing split over multiple paint messages or do the drawing in another thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using wxYield in the draw loop seemed to do the trick.  Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

If your app takes more than 5 seconds to draw, then it must be doing some heavy duty calculations.  Most of the time, say when the windows is moved or hidden then shown, what is drawn will not be changing.  You should therefore store the output from the calculations in a cache, so it can be redrawn in a flash as required.  If something changes, so that the calculations need to be redone, the calculation should be done in a separate thread and the cache updated when completed.

The nature of the cache depends on the nature of your calculation.  The simplest, conceptually, would be an in memory bitmap from which pixels can be copied when required.  In reality, this is only appropriate if the calculations involve the color of individual pixels and you are using a double-buffering scheme.  Probably you can store something like geometric primitives ( lines, squares, etc ) and redraw from these.

The advantage of doing this is that it not only solves the Win7 problem, but it will also make the app more responsive to the user, and therefore much more pleasant to use.